# @PostAuthorize not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to build a simple handler method that will prevent users to browse item's that belong to different user. The method is below:

```
@PostAuthorize("principal.username == #model['username']")
@RequestMapping(value = "/show/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String single(@PathVariable Long id, Model model)  {
    Item item = itemService.findById(id);
    model.addAttribute("item", item);
    model.addAttribute("username", item.getUser().getUsername());
    return "item";
}
```

so the main idea is to compare principal.username with the username stored in the model. I'm using Spring 5.0.5, security 5.0.4. Java Config without boot. My config holds (amnogst other things)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  ...
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

@Override
protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
    final DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler 
      = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    return expressionHandler;
  }
}
```

Despite of this, I'm able to login and than via direct url access items of different user. Any hint is welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so in case others experience a same problem. The problem is that I was using a `@Pre/@PostAuthorize` annotation on a Controller. Controllers are typically not behind an interface, and by the default, the aspect that configure the behaviour didn't kick in.

The solution for me was to `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` on a `WebConfig` class that scan packages in search for controllers:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"rs.saga.web"})
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this method security config to your project. This configuration act as globally and of-course your `proxyTargetClass = true` so that, spring can generate proxy for your controller class also.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.expression.OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    /*
        We can enable annotation-based security using the @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity annotation
        on any @Configuration instance. 

    */

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks ataur, definitely a good advice, proxyTargetClass definitely make sense. however, it's still not working. Do you have any advice, of how to debug if the annotatoin is even being considered. By the way I've added a DefaultMethodSecurityExepressionHandler, and using your config from now on

Comment: What is your `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.*"})` value?

Comment: well, on the security config classes I don't have any

Comment: Did you configure it anywhere in the project ?

Comment: of course, I mean, custom user detail service is picked up since its in the package where services reside. If no further ides, I'll try to strip down a project to minimal and post a github link

Comment: upvoting, your answer led me the right path, however, `proxyTargetClass` didn't help, but I answered below how I actually resolved it.